# An error while processing the validating sql scripts(ACUMATICA UPGRADE 18.217.002 to 19.207.0026)

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to upgrade acumatica from 18.217 to 19.207. There is a customization which depended on FSCause and FSResolution Data Access Class which have been removed from 19.207 and the user data fields moved to attributes section. I have decided to delete those user defined fields from the customization and when I publish it it generates a validation error:

````
     Validating Binary Files
    Validating Sql Scripts
    **An error while processing the validating sql scripts**
    **Validation failed.**```
    The trace error is
````

```
29/02/2020 11:59:19 AM Information:
Redirect7:/ScienceScope/(W(10))/frames/projectbrowser.aspx$target=ServiceOrder17JUNE2019

   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.PX.Web.UI.IPXDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBoundInternal()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(Dictionary`2 A_0, List`1 A_1)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(PXCallbackResultMethod A_0, XmlWriter A_1)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(PXCallbackResultMethod A_0)
```

```
How can I resolve this issue ?
```

Comment: If you are trying to upgrade with the customization in place, try unpublishing your customization before the upgrade.  You should test it on a sandbox instance.  I find that I can better troubleshoot my customizations by building it in the upgraded instance as Visual Studio will validate my code and point me directly to my problem in most cases.

Comment: I unpublished all my customization before the upgrade. Currently I'm publishing all the customizations after the upgrade. I have run the code in visual studio and it was successfully. I tried accessing the customization file in visual studio and they were not available. It seems visual studio cannot open unpublished customization

Comment: I didn’t catch it the first time.  The issue appears to be in a SQL script.  If you can’t find the script with the issue, you can view the project code to search for the table reference.  I am working from memory right now, so let me know if you need help finding the SQL script.

Comment: Check Database Scripts tab in the customization project.  If that doesn’t help find it, use File... Edit Project XML to see all the project code and search for your sql script.

Comment: I have accessed the Database scripts and deleted the two fields in it but it still prints out **An error while processing the validating sql scripts**

Comment: Is there anything more to the message you get when publishing than what you posted already?  I am out of ideas if that is all we have to go on.

Comment: I got a solution by creating a CstValidationIgnore.txt file in visual studio in App_Data folder and placed the error in it then uploaded to my files section in acumatica and published the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes after an upgrade inappropriate errors can be shown which force validation can be enforced to ignore the error by creating a CstValidationIgnore.txt file in visual studio and adding it to your project. To learn more about it visit acumatica 2019R2 documentation at [To Use an Ignore List for the Validation Errors](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=282cc58a-4700-4e9d-8cf6-4641e625c0d6)